# Is there a top to the map, and how do you know you've reached it?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

Is there at some point where you will hit some kind of roof on the map, making you unable to go higher?

If I was to stack boxes upon boxes to go higher and higher, would at some point I be stopped by an invisible force?

Or simpler, if I was to glitch and always go up, would at some point be stopped?

Also, if there's a top, how high is it?

Comment: My guess is probably, but besides trying for yourself, I don't think anyone else will have the answer unless they too have tried.

Comment: Why is this being so heavily downvoted?

Comment: I have no idea. My guess is that 'I could have just tried it myself' but damn, that could apply to pretty much any question on this site. So downvoter, could you explain why you downvoted this?

Comment: If I had to take a guess on the downvotes, I'd guess that it may be due to the high volume of BotW questions you've asked. At this point, some of these questions just seem like you're asking for the sake of asking a question. Why would a map height limit really matter to the average player?

Comment: My reasoning for downvoting this question is that it is highly hypothetical and irrelevant. Who needs to use the full height of the map and for what?

Comment: When thinking in speedrunning terms, nothing is irrelevant.

Comment: I upvoted this question since I find it very interesting and clever: it's not straightforward how to go that high plus it could be useful to reach certain places as mountain peaks.

Comment: Upvoted it, once you are done with the game and can start exploring (although the Gannon is still there), one of the first thing I wanted to do was to find out about the "roof" thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is in fact a top to the map.  People have used the magnesis flying trick and I would assume the Octoballoon flying trick to reach the top.

There are a number of videos on youtube showing these clever use of game mechanics.

Comment: You should link one of those videos in your answer.

Comment: Continued my research, found this, https://media.giphy.com/media/xUPGcdJuZmk1wdCV0Y/giphy.gif

Comment: @Fredy31 consider posting your own answer then ☺

Comment: It adds to @Jonathan answer. So I'll leave this here.

Comment: But how high is it? like for example, how much barrels would you need to stack on each other? Or (if you could which you can't) how much bokolins would it take?